# How to write ErrorDocument command in htaccess depend on language URL?

Tags: .htaccess, custom-error-pages

In a multi language website, where I need to set up a custom 404 page for each language. I want to get language from URL.

`www.../lang/page/`

How to write `ErrorDocument` command in `.htaccess` so that it depends on the language URL?

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404/
```

Comment: Can you please clarify, whether you _need_ to use different (static) files, or just to provide a different _response_ depending on the language, which could be generated dynamically by a script?

Comment: when user is on deutch version it should be redirect to 404 page /de/404/, now the redirect is always to default language version /en/404/

Comment: I don't know if inserting any environment variables (created via `SetEnvIf`, to extract the language from the request uri) into that URL "argument" for ErrorDocument is possible, you could give it a try. An alternative could be to use mod_rewrite, the "usual" RewriterConds to exclude any existing files or folders, and then a RewriteRule to rewrite to the "correct" file matching the language. But with that, I don't think you can set the 404 status code, so it would still have to be actual _scripts_ that issue the appropriate HTTP status first.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the language code is a two character lowercase string in the first path segment of the requested URL-path. If absent, this defaults to `en`.

Try the following:

```
# Get 2 char language code from URL (default to "en") and assign to LANG env var
SetEnvIf ^ ^ LANG=en
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/([a-z]{2})/" LANG=$1

# Set ErrorDocument dynamically using the language code
# Requires Apache 2.4.13+
# The 2nd argument to the ErrorDocument directive must be prefixed with a slash
# in the source code itself for it to be interpreted as a local path.
ErrorDocument 404 /%{reqenv:LANG}/404/
```

Using expression syntax to generate a dynamic `ErrorDocument` string and get the value of the environment variable requires Apache 2.4.13+.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument